# Get today's date - Different timezone

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

I just wanted to know whether the following SQL is good to convert US server time to Thailand date. As we have 12 hours difference in the time, and TH time is ahead of U.S time

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
               TO_CHAR(
                       SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Bangkok', 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                      'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS TODAY
FROM dual;
```

It works perfectly fine. But are there any other better way to convert timestamp of server from one timezone to another as I need to compare today's date based on this result in my outer SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could **CAST** the **timestamp** to your desired **timezone**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH data AS (
  2  SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Bangkok' tm_bangkok FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT tm_bangkok,
  5         CAST(tm_bangkok AT TIME ZONE 'EST' AS TIMESTAMP) tm_est
  6  FROM data;

TM_BANGKOK                                    TM_EST
--------------------------------------------- ----------------------------
03-NOV-15 12.54.18.951000 PM ASIA/BANGKOK     03-NOV-15 12.54.18.951000 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to cast a TIMESTAMP to CHAR and then back to TIMESTAMP again. Simply do

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Bangkok' AS TODAY 
FROM dual;
```